# Foreigner son-in-law went on a killing spree, then formed a militia just to stand around for awhile... did I miss something?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm working through my first, long-term play-through after dozens (or, if I'm being honest, hundreds) of short attempts to figure out the mechanics. I'm finally getting into where some weird stuff is happening and I feel like I missed out on something.

I'm playing as a West African count in Oualata. I married one of my daughters matrilinearly to some young chap out of the Canary Islands and he came down and lived pretty quietly in my court for several years. Then there was an epic 12 month period where he seemed to go berserk.

My wife, the spymaster with an intrigue of 23 scheming at home, was murdered on his orders. No event said so, there was never any warning about it, nothing. Just that sad, red little skull saying she was murdered by him. I tried to lock him up but didn't have a righteous imprisonment (which doesn't really make sense, but whatever) and based on my state intrigue, there was only a 25% chance of getting him. There are plenty of other women in the area and I could use some more prestige boosts from marrying them, and I really didn't want that guy to get away and plot against me from somewhere else, so I married up another spymaster (20 intrigue) in another court, appointed her and set her off scheming.

1 month later, she was dead. Murdered by this same guy. Not so amusing, but hey, more prestige from marriage. No biggie.

Well, I ended up clearing out every spymaster in West Africa. In 6 months, he killed 5 spymasters, all with 20 or greater intrigue. The amusement came back at this point because now nobody in the kingdom had a spymaster with intrigue better than 8, but somehow this dude killed off the best spies in the kingdom. In 6 months!

He laid low for 2-3 months and then I got an event. This guy, his name was Mula, was going to form a militia or something called Mula's Host and he was going to take over the Canary Islands. The only choice was something like "Yeah, okay, you go do that...", which was quite fitting because we're literally in the middle of nowhere and there's absolutely no boats anywhere in the kingdom. So his band of 2000 big, tough baddies stood in Oualata as their numbers dwindled due to supply problems I guess, for 5 years until they were all dead. In the mean time, when I moused over my heirs, it would say "Heir to Mula's Host" rather than Oualata.

So clearly, this dude was up to something all along and didn't want my spymasters to uncover whatever his plot was. It was a pretty busy year for him. This is what he looked like:

[image: murderous jerk]

What plot event was he working on? Why did he go crazy and kill everybody, just to form a band of angry men who declared war on an island when they didn't have boats and they just stood around until the died in the desert? Why did my heirs show that the title they would get was called Mula's Host rather than Oualata?

As with almost everything that comes up in this game, I feel like I missed out on something here.

Comment: Could we maybe get a screenshot of this guy? It would help a lot to know his stats/traits/claims etc.

Comment: @JMR I added him -- his intrigue is better than I thought it was, but still doesn't seem right he was so great at killing my spymasters. I also don't know if his claims would have disappeared after his militia disbanded and that's why none show up? Maybe he had a weak claim on the Canary Islands or something before he went nuts?

Comment: And after his militia disbanded, he went to another court which is why he had a different liege (and then he died).

Comment: @tpg2114 Yeah, dead people lose all their claims.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167425/ckii-aquitaine-hughs-host . This wouldn't explain the killing spree but the answer explains what happened when he raised that army.

Comment: @Studoku Thanks, it's surprisingly hard to find information for a game with multiplayer support when the event uses the word "host." OP in that question was on the receiving end of the army's attack whereas here I was the home county for the crazy guy leading the army. I have a hunch the "raise an army and take the homeland" event is something that could be discovered and/or stopped which is why he killed all my spymasters, but I'm hoping somebody could answer definitively.

Comment: I would have guessed that he got the Lunatic or Possessed trait which can cause NPCs to commit murder without any obvious motive, but he appears to be sane. At lest he was when he died. He does however have "Deceitful" which AFAIK makes NPCs much more active plotters.

Comment: As far as I'm aware though host invasions are not a plot, simply an event. In fact, when an NPC decides to start a host invasion, the game explicitly gives the target 2 years notice. Musa here's only concern as far as spymasters related to the host invasion would be his target's spymaster trying to raise plot power to assassinate him.

Comment: @JMR In a game where so many strange things can happen, the murder-spree could just be coincidental with the invasion thing. Maybe that is the answer, but it is a heck of a coincidence. At least it made an amusing story, to me anyway. Probably not my poor wives/spymasters though.

Comment: Right, and the host just wandering around the desert and dying is easily explained as the AI being too shortsighted to realize that it wants to attack a target it can't reach. It wants to do a thing, so it does a thing and screw whether it can actually achieve that thing or not. Unfortunately because of how complicated this game is, without having the exact game state to look at it will be very difficult to provide an answer to this question.

Comment: @JMR Unfortunately it was ironmode and I kept playing after it happened so I don't have the game state. And I'm guessing I will probably never have that combination/series of events happen again if nobody else has experienced it.

Comment: Characters with the "Become Spymaster" ambition will often try to get the job through klingon promotion and murder the spymaster of their liege. That might explain why he killed each of your wifes after you made her your spymaster.

Answer (score 1):

Well the inheritance can be complicated but basically (making some assumptions since I don't have a screenshot of his living profile) he had a claim on the islands.

Unlanded characters with a claim on a holding might (random event) start a war with event troops (which will be named with this "host" thing). When they are ready for war it will send a message to their lord (but the lord has no choice in the matter)

Because he then joined your family, his temporary title would go to his heirs which happened to be yours as well.

Since he couldn't actually move his troops to the objective (which his more or less a bug) he ended up losing the war because he couldn't get any warscore.

As for the scary killing spree, I assume it is some bad (or good) RNG that ended up in that, as far as I know there is no event (even not announced as such) where a guy shows up at your court and kills everyone.

And last point you shouldn't set your wife as a spymaster since it will bring you a smaller total bonus than if you had a different spymaster (the +50% from the wife isn't counted in this case). The second reason is that she might kill you if she feels like it (while a guy you keep giving gifts to tends not to).